# Multi-input AND gates from 2-input AND gates

Tags: digital-logic, gate-driving

To realize a 3-input AND gate from 2-input AND gates, we need 2 such 2-input AND gates. Assuming we have infinite supply of 2-input AND gates, can we obtain a general formula for the number of 2-input AND gates required to obtain a n-input AND gate?
Note that we have to minimize the resource usage.

Comment: Is this an assignment? | Look at the number of inputs and outputs. Given that each gate has 2 inputs and adding the output from a chained gate uses one of them how could it be possible to get more than N extra inputs if you add N extra 2-input gates? | If you use eg one gate as output and feed it with two gates and build up a tree structure the same "rule" applies | ie "by inspection" there is no possible superior method in terms of inputs per gate. | The result is always N+1 inputs for N gates.

Answer (score 3):

To implement an N input AND gate you require N-1 two-input AND gates.

The simplest topology is:

[image: schematic]

Comment: This is an obvious answer. But is it the maximum optimal solution we can attain? I am not sure about it.

Comment: @randomos I think the obvious answer is the optimal solution here.

Comment: It is optimal. For any given existing network of AND gates, adding one more gate turns one input into two, for a net gain of one input. You can't do any better than this. For optimal *performance*, however, you would of course organize the gates as a tree.